# SSL error only with Indy, HTTPRIO does not occur

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, certificate, indy

I have to communicate with a government API. This API requires a digital certificate to make requests.

If I make the request using the Indy components (TIdHTTP and TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL), I get the following exception:

"EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate".

If I make the request using a THTTPRIO or THTTPReqResp component, no exception occurs and I am able to get the response from the request.

Why does the problem only occur with Indy? And what would be a possible solution?

I'm making the Indy request as follows:

```
procedure TFrmApp.btnIndyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response: TStringStream;
  Url: string;
begin

  Response := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  Url := 'https://testes.tcm.go.gov.br:8443/passaporte/api/auth/representacoes';
  try
    try

      // HTTPIndy is TIdHTTP
      // OpenSSLIndy is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

      HTTPIndy.IOHandler := OpenSSLIndy;

      OpenSSLIndy.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'cert.pem';
      OpenSSLIndy.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'cert_nokeys.pem';
      OpenSSLIndy.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'server.key';

      HTTPIndy.Get(Url, Response);

      { Response handling... }

    except
      on E: Exception do
        MessageDlg('Error: ' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + E.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    end;
  finally
    Response.Free;
  end;

end;
```

The .PEM and .KEY files were generated from .PFX using OpenSSL (1.1.1d), using the following commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "MyCert.pfx" -passin pass:MyPass -out "cert.pem" -nodes    

openssl pkcs12 -in "MyCert.pfx" -passin pass:MyPass -out "cert_nokeys.pem" -clcerts -nokeys

openssl pkcs12 -in "MyCert.pfx" -passin pass:MyPass -out "key.pem" -passout pass:MyPass -nocerts

openssl rsa -in "key.pem" -passin pass:MyPass -out "server.key"
```

The request using HTTPRIO, I'm doing as follows:

```
procedure TFrmApp.btnRIOClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response: TStringStream;
  Url: string;
begin

  Response := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  Url := 'https://testes.tcm.go.gov.br:8443/passaporte/api/auth/representacoes';
  try
    try

      // HTTPRIO is THTTPRIO

      HTTPRIO.URL := Url;

      HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.Get(Response);

      { Response handling ... }

    except
      on E: Exception do
        MessageDlg('Error: ' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + E.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    end;
  finally
    Response.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Where is your certificate handling when using `THTTPRIO`? Also, Indy does not support OpenSSL 1.1.1 yet. Do you have the same problem if you use OpenSSL 1.0.2 to create the certificate files? I don't know if OpenSSL 1.1.1 outputs files that are compatible with 1.0.2. Clearly the server is rejecting the client certificate you are using. Do you get the same error if you use `openssl.exe` to make the same request? If so, then it is not an Indy issue but an OpenSSL issue

Comment: THTTPRIO automatically detects that the request needs a digital certificate, and calls up the Windows certificate selection screen. I believe that with this he ends up using the Windows encryption API and does not need OpenSSL, so there is no error (Maybe I'm saying the wrong thing). Even using OpenSSL 1.0.2u the error continues. I tried to make the request with openssl s_client, I don't get the same error but I get:

Comment: I don't know if this would be an error, I never messed with the s_client log.

CONNECTED(00000278)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.tcm.go.gov.br
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.tcm.go.gov.br
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1

Comment: If you can't get `s_client` to work, then you likely won't get `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to work, either. Whatever you have to do to get `s_client` working can then be applied to `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` as needed.  So get this working outside of Indy first, then come back to Indy.

Comment: And if `THTTPRIO` is calling up the Windows certificate selection, then it is definitely not using OpenSSL at all. IIRC, Embarcadero doesn't use Indy/OpenSSL in HTTPRIO anymore, they use their own cross-platform implementation now, which uses WinInet on Windows.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by exporting my certificate to PFX using the Windows Certificate Manager tool (certmgr.msc), checking the option to export the private key as well. With that my PFX file went from 4 Kb to 10 KB, I generated the PEM and KEY files again through OpenSSL and everything worked again.